# "Wrap up in" alternatives in this context

Tags: word-choice

> When I was a child my mother used to **wrap me up in** heavy clothes.
>
> When I started going school she   used to [gap] my uniform.

I know the phrasal verb **put on,** can I use **put me on** in the gap.

Please explain.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

“Put me on” is no good in this context. That’s its own phrasal verb- to “put someone on” is to trick them, usually in good fun, as a joke. You could say just “put on” but then it’s ambiguous whether she put your uniform on you or herself. I would go with:

> When I started going to school she used to *dress me in* my uniform.

This makes it clear that she used to dress *you* in your uniform, not herself.